# How much bit encryption devise gem using for password?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encryption, devise, rubygems

I am working with devise gem for authentication and i know that its using bcrypt. I want to ask that how much bit encryption it is using for encrypting the password.As the bcrypt documantation is telling its consists of

```
$version$iteraion$salt(128 bit encrypted)+hash
```

.I want to ask can we consider devise alternative for 256 bit encryption.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Devise is using [bcrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) (per [default](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/database_authenticatable.rb)). bcrypt is a hashing function not a encryption algorithm, therefore the term `bit` doesn't suit in the context of bcrypt.

It might be worth noting that bcrypt supports only passwords up to 56 bytes.

Comment: Bcrypt is slightly hard to assign a bit value to block size as it uses structures of different size internally. I wouldn't have a problem calling SHA1 160 bit or SHA512 512 bit. However, the OP is clearly confused and could make a very wrong decision without understanding the design behind bcrypt. I would mention the work factor, and why counting bits is missing important considerations for solving shadow password problem, even if it was possible.